# Why does std::insert require CopyConstructibility?

Tags: c++

Why doesn't this code work?
There is nothing about CopyConstructibility in the docs for the insert method of std::map: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert

I can construct std::pair with the second element being my non_copyable class, but I cannot insert it into map, even though the very first overload of the insert method takes a const value_type&, so this should work fine.

Can someone help me understand why std::map requires this CopyConstructibility?

```
#include <utility>
#include <map>

struct non_copyable {
    non_copyable(){}

private:
    non_copyable(const non_copyable&);
};

int main() {
    std::pair<int, non_copyable> p; // this works!

    std::map<int, non_copyable> m;
    m.insert(std::pair<int, non_copyable>()); // this does NOT work
}
```

EXAMPLE: https://wandbox.org/permlink/r3H6CqehfqnHPXDL

Comment: Because it makes a *copy* of the pair.

Comment: Try `emplace` instead. It's what it exists for.

Comment: The explicitly defined copy constructor disables the implicit definition of a move constructor. You'd need `non_copyable(non_copyable&&) = default;` to choose the correct overload of insert, if available (it is in c++17 unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: `emplace` wasn't available before c++11.
`insert` have more than one form, with ONLY ONE available before c++11, which was copying the variable (it used const-lvalue reference `const T &`).   But in the new standards, you can use `emplace`, or you can use `insert` itself with the "move" variants (that takes `T &&`), but this needs you to define "move" constructor. `non_copyable(non_copyable&&) = default;`
Try to read about "reference types", "copy/move constructors", "copy/move assignments"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... even though the very first overload of the insert method takes a **const value_type&**, so this should work fine.

No, actually in this case, the correct overload resolution candidate for:

```
m.insert(std::pair<int, non_copyable>());
```

is this overloaded member function:

```
template< class P >
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( P&& value );
```

Now [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) describes why this doesn't work:

> ... only participates in overload resolution if `std::is_constructible<value_type, P&&>::value == true`.

Your `non_copyable` is not constructible:

```
using M = std::map<int, non_copyable>;
using P = std::pair<int, non_copyable>;
std::is_constructible<M::value_type, P&&>::value; // false
```

because there's no available constructor including a default, implicit move constructor generated by the compiler.

The reason `non_copyable` even disabled its default, implicit move constructor is because of having a user-defined copy constructor, as [documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor):

> If no user-defined move constructors are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), and all of the following is true:
>
> **there are no user-declared copy constructors**
>
> there are no user-declared copy assignment operators
>
> there are no user-declared move assignment operators
>
> there are no user-declared destructors

Now giving `non_copyable` a move constructor becomes your responsbility:

```
struct non_copyable {
    non_copyable(){}
    non_copyable(non_copyable &&) = default;

private:
    non_copyable(const non_copyable&);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested why you have to make any copies at all hence provide copy constructible types even if you could construct a pair directly (emplace it) inside of a map.

It is because to provide the required performance the internal representation of the std::map is usually implemented as a balanced binary search tree (eventually as another data structure with similar performance characteristics) requiring some specific order of stored elements. So after adding or deleting some elements the order may be broken and to preserve its correctness occasional internal moves of the stored elements will be needed.